# The truth within

Tags: liars

Someone living in the remote cabin that you do put a virus onto your PC.

Here are your suspects:

Your brother, Liam, who only tells the truth about his opinions.
Your sister, Irene, who tells the truth 50% of the time, is a snitch, and is close to her brother, Aaron.
Your brother, Aaron, who is sometimes truthful, hates lying, but will usually tell the truth if he did something bad.
Your sister, Renada, who often confuses you in such a way that you can't tell if it's a lie or the truth.

You can't ask anyone who you've already asked without getting the same answer.
  So, who installed the virus?

Please provide an explanation along with your answer.

Hint:

> It's totally fine if you don't know.

Comment: Liam only cares about his opinions. He is stuck up and lies.

Comment: Ask Liam "who is most likely to install the virus"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is:

> There's no way to know for sure.  You have **zero** sources of reliable information.
>  -Liam is only know to speak the truth if he has an opinion, meaning only when he is unsure.  His reliability is **unknown** at all times.
>  -Irene is known to be **unreliable**.
>  -Aaron is "usually" likely to be truthful in some situations, but never 100%.  His reliability is **unknown** at all times.
>  -Renada's reliability is **unknown** at all times.

Alternatively

> There might be some wordplay or hidden message here, and the first letter of the names of the siblings spelling out LIAR hints at that, but the question is not currently tagged that way.

Comment: I honestly thought it would take a while longer for someone to get this. Nice job! They are all united against you.

Answer (score 1):

One way to get the answer would be:

> Ask Aaron, “Did you install the virus?”
> If he says no then he didn’t install it. If he says yes, he did.
> This works because Aaron is truthful if he did something bad.

Then:

> If he said no, ask Irene who installed the virus.
> Since she’s a snitch, and you know it isn’t Aaron(whom she would protect), you will get the right answer.

Comment: Aaron is sometimes truthful about bad things he's done.